# Is it possible it run VMware Player 12.5.9 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, vmware

The installation of VMware Player 12.5.9 ran smoothly but when I'm trying to run it

> user@path:~$ vmplayer

it doesn't complain, that means no messages in the terminal window and no dialog boxes, but it  doesn't start .

> ps ax | grep vmplayer
> has only grep in its output.

It is no problem to install and run VMware Player 15.5 (and with patches from mkubecek also 14.1 is possible), but I would need to run 12.5.9 for evaluation purposes concerning smart card compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

after having installed VMware Player (VMware-Player-12.5.9-7535481.x86_64.bundle or your preferred version!)

make a backup of a library installed by vmware installer:

```
cd /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libz.so.1/ 

sudo mv libz.so.1 libz.so.1.orig
```

make a symbolic link to the library of the linux distribution:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 .
```

At github.com Michael Kubecek maintains a patch project for the vmware host modules

```
 sudo apt-get install git
```

change to the directory where you would like to store the sourcecode:

```
 cd <a directory of your choice>
```

make a local copy of the repository

```
 git clone https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules.git
```

checkout your preferred version!

```
 cd vmware-host-modules git checkout player-12.5.9
```

The steps above need to be made only once

```
make && sudo make install 

sudo depmod -a 

sudo /etc/init.d/vmware restart
```

The last three lines need to be run after every kernel update
(you need to be in the <directory of your choice>/vmware-host-modules)

It also works on Debian 10.